# Save $.ajax response to variable (xml)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I'm trying to save the .ajax response, which queries a xml from a REST interface, but I am not successful. Until now the code works, and I get the response, but optimally I would like to parse some of the items into javascript variables or at least save the whole response into one variable. My code looks is the following:

```
// the actual request
function request(url) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "localhost:8080/package/rest/pubs/getpubswithinbbox?south=41.886288445510516&west=12.483901977539062&north=41.893700240146295&east=12.500102519989014",
        dataType : "xml",
        success : function (data) {
            console.log("Successfully queried API!");
            console.log(data);

        },

        error : function (data) {
            console.log("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        }
    });
};

//Code Ends
```

Using `console.log(data)` I also can view the file as a document, but as already mentioned, I would like to save some XML-Elements into variables (or the whole XML document for a later processing).

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><osm generator="Overpass API" version="0.6">
<note>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.</note>
<meta osm_base="2014-06-05T12:35:02Z"/>

  <node id="1701218666" lat="41.8885564" lon="12.4950752">
    <tag k="amenity" v="pub"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Camden Town"/>
  </node>
</osm>
```

Do you have any tips of how to proceed with my code snippets? I want to set the request to sync by using `async: false`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create div tag in html body like   and in jquery ajax part  just    use $(#result).append(data); inside sucess function

Answer (score 0):

The response object you define within your success/error callbacks can be used as any other JS object. So if you have an existing variable you want to assign it to, do so (though try to avoid cluttering the global namespace) or even attach it to the page using jQuery's .data() function. Example:

```
// the actual request
function request(url) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "localhost:8080/package/rest/pubs/getpubswithinbbox?south=41.886288445510516&west=12.483901977539062&north=41.893700240146295&east=12.500102519989014",
        dataType : "xml",
        success : function (data) {
            console.log("Successfully queried API!");
            console.log(data);
            $('body').data('APIResult',data);
        },

        error : function (data) {
            console.log("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        }
    });
};
```

Then, elsewhere in your script, whenever you want to reference or use the API response, simply call it or assign it to a local var as such:

```
var APIData = $('body').data('APIResult');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foo = data
```

Note that `foo` will remain undefined until the asynchronous function has been resolved.

You should probably declare `foo` in the scope you want it in (using `var foo` outside the call to `ajax`).